# Testing Node CLI tool that listens to stdin.isTTY?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, command-line, command-line-interface

How can I implement a test that verifies the different behaviours of `stdin.isTTY` in a Node CLI tool?

I have implemented a CLI tool in Node that expects data to be either piped through the terminal or passed as command line args:

**cli.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

const { stdin, exit } = require('process');

const parseCliArgs = (argv) => {
  // parse args...
  return argv;
};

const readFromStdin = async () => {
  stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    let data = '';

    stdin.on('readable', () => {
      let chunk;
      while ((chunk = stdin.read()) !== null) {
        data += chunk;
      }
    });

    stdin.on('end', () => {
      resolve(data);
    });

    stdin.on('error', err => reject(err));
  }));
};


const main = async (argv) => {
  let args;

  console.info('isTTY: ', stdin.isTTY);

  if (stdin.isTTY) {
    console.info('Parse arguments');
    args = parseCliArgs(argv);
  } else {
    console.info('Read from stdin');
    args = await readFromStdin();
  }
  console.info(args);
};


main(process.argv)
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    exit(1);
  });
```

---

The tool works as expected when used from the terminal, e.g. piping data to the CLI script:

```
$ echo "hello" | ./cli.js
isTTY:  undefined
Read from stdin
hello
```

And passing data as command line arguments also works as expected:

```
$ ./cli.js hello
isTTY:  true
Parse arguments
[
  '/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.2.0/bin/node',
  '[my local path]/cli.js',
  'hello'
]
```

---

Now, I have attempted to write a test that verifies these behaviours:

**cli.spec.js**

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

// pipe stdio and stdout from child process to node's stdio and stdout
const CHILD_PROCESS_OPTIONS = { stdio: 'inherit' };

describe('cli test', () => {
  it('pipe data to CLI tool', () => {
    const command = `echo "hello" | ${__dirname}/cli.js`;
    execSync(command, CHILD_PROCESS_OPTIONS);
  });

  it('pass data as CLI args', () => {
    const command = `${__dirname}/cli.js "hello"`;
    execSync(command, CHILD_PROCESS_OPTIONS);
  });
});
```

The `pipe data to CLI tool` test works as expected (and gives the same output as when executed from command line).

The `pass data as CLI args` test hangs indefinitely. Looking at the output, I find that

```
isTTY:  undefined
Read from stdin
```

Based on this observation I draw the conclusion that `stdin.isTTY` is not handled correctly (which causes the promise returned from the `readFromStdin()` function to remain unresolved, thus hanging the test).

---

- How can I make the test `pass data as CLI args` pass?
- Is it possible to mock the `process.stdin.isTTY` in the child process?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that these tests were working as expected, but not in all environments. The tests passed as expected when executing from the terminal (e.g. `npm test` and friends). However, the original implementation did not pass, and from that point I attempted to use the debugger in my IDE to find a solution and it still does not work. Please submit another answer in case there is another solution that works in all environments.

Comment: I added an answer that dives a little deeper on why this is the case. It's not perfect, but adds more info :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running into this, it's related to how Node.js spawns the child processes. Specifically it's the [stdio option](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) the child_process API supports. An [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/31409) related to this is open in Node.js core.

When you spawn a child process in Node.js it has pipes/streams between it and the parent to handle stdio [by default](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio). Therefore the parent can call `child.stdin.write()` to send data to stdin of the child and also read the `child.stderr` and `child.stdout` streams.

The stdin (AFAICT) is pretty confusing when using the sync `child_process` APIs since you can't `write()` to the child at all. You can pass a Stream reference per the docs, but I couldn't figure it out using tty.Read/WriteStream.

I ran into this and found that setting the `options.stdio[0]` to `inherit` resolved the issue. This is because my parent (test) process has not been passed anything via stdin and therefore has the TTY flag set and the child will inherit this and work as expected. I thought `ignore` might work but it didn't.

TLDR; Here's my [complete test case](https://github.com/evanshortiss/kube-count-resources/blob/7ec9d17a6a1d39df3d187f1e53502b2553eba089/test/test.js#L37-L50), and an example below. For testing a Node.js CLI where your CLI detects pipes via `isTTY` but also supports file args try this:

```
try {
  const stdout = execSync('your-cli.js some-file.txt', {
    stdio: [
      // Child will inherit process.stdin of
      // this parent process. This has isTTY
      // set to true, so the child will also
      // be set to true and parse the "some-file.txt"
      // arg instead of waiting on stdin
      'inherit',
      // Capture stdout from child. This is returned from
      // the call, and attached to an exception if one is
      // thrown, i.e error.stdout
      'pipe',
      // Capture stderr from child. This will be attached
      // as a "stderr" property if an exception is raised
      'pipe'
    ]
  });
  console.log('Child Process stdout was:', stdout)
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error in child. Child stderr was:', e.stderr) 
}
```